# Mock security context for JPA integration test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to test a spring JPA repository interface to ensure my mappings are correct. My entity extends a base entity which is annotated with..

```
@EntityListeners(BaseEntityEventListener.class)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {...
```

The event listener populates some audit properties..

```
public class BaseEntityEventListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void onPreInsert(BaseEntity baseEntity){
        MyUserPrincipal principal = (MyUserPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = principal.getUsername();
        baseEntity.setCreationUser(username);
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        baseEntity.setCreationDate(ts);
    }...
```

This is ok but when I want to test the repository I get a null pointer for the SecurityContextHolder.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RepositoryTest {
    @Autowired private MyRepository myRepo;

    @Test
    public void testSaveEntity() throws Exception {
        Entity entity = new Entity(TEST_ID);
        myRepo.save(entity);
    }...
```

When event listener class is called from test the security context is not set. I have tried using @WithMockUser but this doesn't seem to work. Could I maybe wrap call to security context in a service and then somehow mock this call in my integration test. How do I set mock on entity listener if this is an option. When I use @CreatedBy and @CreatedDate the security context is not an issue but I need to manually use @PreInsert for a separate reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error you got? Maybe because it cannot get the user. 
You can try:

```
val userPrincipal =
                new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username,
                        "",
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        authorities);
        val auth = new TestingAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, authorities);
        auth.setAuthenticated(true);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```